✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android - Versions found: N/A - Version supported: 34.0.0
"Hello,
I'm encountering an issue with my Android project configuration. The build process is indicating that Android SDK version 34.0.0 is required, but my project settings don't specify any version (currently showing 'N/A').
Here are my environment details:
Android Studio/IDE version: latest version
ALso i used sdkmanager --version to know which version my sdk is but its throwing a java-jar error. I need serious help here
How can I resolve this version compatibility issue and ensure my project uses the required Android SDK version 34.0.0?
Thank you."
I tried to delete and install the whole andriod studio packages again, e didnt work,
I also tried to know my sdk version, it didnt work as well
this is also what i have in the photos[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/csAFqQgY.png)
